# How to delete a specific article from all BOMs?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

my task is to delete a specific article from all bills of materials (BOMs) in AX 2009.

I understand that the `BOMTable` table contains the header and the `BOM` table contains the lines. They are connected via the `BOMId`.

The `BOM` table holds a field `ItemId` which is the `InventTable.ItemId`.

Is the assumption correct, that it is sufficent to delete all rows from `BOM` table where the `BOM.ItemId == InventTable.ItemId` ?
And is there anything else which needs to be considered?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct. If you want to clear a specific item from all BOM *versions*, you would just remove all BOM records with a matching ItemId.

However, this does affect all Versions of all BOMs. I believe if you want to be able to maintain historical versions, you would need to additionally reference BOMVersion and pull only Active BOMs.

Also, this change would only take effect on new production of the item going forward; any open production orders of items affected by the change would still have the old BOM.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It makes sense to maintain the historical data. Therefore I will join BOM to BOMVersion with BOMId and only delete the BOM line when BOMVersion.Active is true (BOMVersion.Active == NoYes::YES).